# Trouble handling interactive state for my UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

**I'll start with my view hierarchy**:

ParentView -----> TopBarView (`UIView`) and CollectionView (`UICollectionView`)

**Scenario**:

1) My TopBarView is pinned to the top of ParentView with a height constraint. It is set to handle tap and long-press gestures. Also, my TopBarView's width is equal to that of CollectionView

2) My CollectionView is pinned to the top of the ParentView too! And it has a top padding equal to that of the TopBarView's height. So visually, CollectionView's content starts right below the TopBarView. Also, whenever the CollectionView is scrolled, my TopBarView's constraint is adjusted based on my CollectionView's offset, to visually make it look like it's scrolling along and the inverse is what I'm working on...

**My requirement**:

I'm trying to make the TopBarView scrollable, so that the CollectionView scrolls along with it too

**What I've tried**:

To establish scroll behaviour, I'm simply setting the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of TopBarView to `false`, so that the touch events get passed to the underlying CollectionView, and it works as intended!

**The Problem**:

Since I already support tap gestures and long-press gestures for my TopBarView, I cannot permanently set it to be irresponsive. I have to toggle between the gestures that the user performs i.e: To accept interactions where the user taps or long-presses the view, but deny interactions when user tries to scroll the view(so that the touch events get passed to CollectionView)

**All of the above is mostly just for the context. Here's my problem put simply:**

My view should respond to taps and long-presses. But when scrolled, it should quit responding and pass the scroll to underlying collection view.

There's got to be something probably trivial that I'm missing out on, and I'm here. TYIA!

Comment: Is that what you want: the header view respond to tap and long press and the rest only respond to tap? Can you put a visual example of what you want? also give more detail about this 'mock' view. Collection view supports supplementary views you can use for header and footer.

Comment: @Maysam My header should respond to tap and long-press actions, become irresponsive when scrolled(if at all) to pass the scroll to the underlying view (collection view), and become responsive again at the end of scroll

Comment: What do you mean 'when scrolled'? When it's not visible? How your requirements are different from an ordinary collection view with a header?

Comment: I guess my question is ambiguous right now, let me rephrase it a little better...

Comment: Have edited the question. Hopefully it's clear now :)

Comment: Can you record the screen of simulator and show what have you do so far and what does not work? Gif Brewery can do it or use cmd+shift+5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204328/discussion-between-lok-sn-and-maysam).